# Database decision - Cassandra or PostGres

Tags: database, postgresql, cassandra, architecture, nosql

I'm trying to determine wether or not to use PostGres or Cassandra data store. Data will be inserted to this new store initially via :
1. A batch process to insert 100MB per day.
2. At a later point the existing batch process + CRUD operations at a rate of 20 operations per second.

From reading articles & various conversations with other I have determined:

```
**Cassandra**
Type: NoSql
Read Speed: Fast
Write Speed: Slow
Storage: Distributed Cluster
Scaling: Horizontal
```

---

```
**PostGres**
Type: Relational
Storage: Single Instance
Scaling: Horizontal
```

Some resources I have been reading :

> https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-compare-Postgres-to-Cassandra-for-big-data-application
>
> https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-approach-choosing-a-database-architecture-and-design
>
> https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/sql-vs-nosql-db/?utm_source=tuicool

What other considerations should be taken before making the decision ? Are there other data points I should include in the decision process such as determining the expected number reads, writes, updates, deletes from the table ?

I could utilize PostGres and then migrate to Cassandra at some other point but would prefer to avoid the overhead of a DB migration process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with postgres, because it is more customizable for developers and it is a nosql database combined with the most beautiful parts with sql db.